# Why does this object not get garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

```
function Car() {
    this.interval = {id: null};
    this.i = 0;
    this.start = function() {
        this.interval.id = setInterval(this.go.bind(this), 1000);
    }

    this.go = function() {
        this.i++;
        if (this.i >= 5) {
            console.log("kill");
            this.kill();
        } else {
            console.log("go");
        }
    };

    this.kill = function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval.id);
    };
}

var car = new Car();
car.start();
car = null;
```

When I run the above I get

```
go
go
go
go
kill
```

Shouldn't car object be garbage collected since it is unreachable? How is setInterval able to access the car object? And does the car object continue to exist afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `car` object you created is still reachable by the closure that `setInterval()` is within.  That closure creates a reference to the `car` object so it can't be garbage collected until that closure is also unreachable.

The closure is created because `this.go.bind(this)` has a reference to `this` which is your `car` object.  The JS interpreter knows that the `car` object is still reachable by the `setInterval()` callback function and thus there is still a live reference.

If the `setInterval()` were to stop itself after a certain number of iterations or any other condition, then the object would become eligible for garbage collection because that `setInterval()` reference would no longer be alive and there would be no other references still alive.

Answer (score 1):

```
  this.go.bind(this)
```

This effectively creates a closure that wraps your car (`this`).

As long as that closure is alive, it will keep the car around.

And `setInterval` of course remembers the function it is supposed to run.